# VBA Delete Top 7 Rows in every Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I am trying to delete the top 7 rows in each Worksheet contained within a Workbook. I have the following code, however, I think there is an issue with the loop and I cannot get the code to execute correctly; I would appreciate any help!

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For I = 1 To WS_Count

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet(I).Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
     Next I

  End Sub
```

Comment: `.Rows(8)` will only select `8:8`... Eiter use Scotts `.Range("1:7")` or `.Range(Rows(1), Rows(7))`... however, there is no need for `EntireRow` in both  cases...

Comment: Also... doing it for all sheets better use `Dim I As Variant` and `For Each I In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`... then `I.Range ("1:7").Delete`... you also may want to use the `Shift`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet(I).Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
```

to this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Range("1:7").EntireRow.Delete
```

Also to iterate through all the sheets you can change to this instead:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Range("1:7").EntireRow.delete
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much; the code works and is much more 'efficient' than what I had. However, how would the code change if I wanted the Delete range to vary based on the Sheet name (i.e., delete Rows1to7 in Sheet1 and Rows1to7 & Rows0to20 in Sheet2).

Comment: With if statements or select case statements.  But that is a different question.  Please mark this as the accepted answer and try on your own then post a new question.